# wasteful of life (What is the context this phrase can be used?)

Tags: phrase-usage

> wasteful of life

1. not working (hard)
2. killing living critures

Which one is closer to the phrase above ?

Comment: Usually 'causing unnecessary deaths'.

Comment: the word is **creatures**